# PHP MySQL pagination is slow

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

My table

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id      int(11)     NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
userid  int(11)     NO  MUL NULL     
title   varchar(50) YES     NULL     
hosting varchar(10) YES     NULL     
zipcode varchar(5)  YES     NULL     
lat     varchar(20) YES     NULL     
long    varchar(20) YES     NULL     
msg    varchar(1000)YES MUL NULL     
time    datetime    NO      NULL
```

That is the table. I have simulated 500k rows of data and deleted randomly 270k rows to leave only 230k with an auto increment of 500k.

Here are my indexs

```
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Field   Cardinality Collation   Null
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id            232377    A       
info    BTREE   No  No  userid          2003    A       
lat                                    25819    A   YES
long                                   25819    A   YES
title                                  25819    A   YES
time                                   25819    A
```

With that in mind , here is my query:

> SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `long`>-118.13902802886 AND `long`<-118.08130797114 AND `lat`>33.79987197114 AND `lat`<33.85759202886 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 25

Showing rows 0 - 15 (16 total, Query took 1.5655 sec) [id: 32846 - 540342]

The query only brought me 1 page, but because it had to search all  230k records it still took 1.5 seconds.

Here is the query explained:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      posts   index   NULL            PRIMARY 4       NULL 25     Using where
```

So even if i use where clauses to only get back 16 results I still get a slow query.

Now for example if i do a broader search :

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `long`>-118.2544681443 AND `long`<-117.9658678557 AND `lat`>33.6844318557 AND `lat`<33.9730321443 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 25
```

Showing rows 0 - 24 (25 total, Query took 0.0849 sec) [id: 691 - 29818]

It is much faster when retrieving the first page out of 20 pages and 483 found total but i limit to 25.

but if i ask for the last page

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `long`>-118.2544681443 AND `long`<-117.9658678557 AND `lat`>33.6844318557 AND `lat`<33.9730321443 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 475, 25
```

Showing rows 0 - 7 (8 total, Query took 1.5874 sec) [id: 553198 - 559593]

I get a slow query.

My question is how do I achieve good pagination? When the website goes live I expect when it takes off that posts will be deleted and made daily by the hundreds.
Posts should be ordered by id or timestamp and Id is not sequential because some records will be deleted.
I want to have a standard pagination

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... [Last Page]
```

Comment: Could you add information about the storage engine and indexes?

Comment: I have indexed every column. And it's mysam engine.

Comment: @CrisG do you want a bounty put on this question? eggyal's answer looks pretty good, but you never responded to his final question in the comments. I'd be willing to put a bounty on this for you if you need it answered (once it's open for a bounty).

Comment: @Matt sure I want a bounty on this question.

Comment: @CrisG As soon as it's old enough to put a bounty on it, I'll set one up. Hang tight until then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. What was slowing me down is order by. Since I would call a limit and the the further down I asked to go the more it had to sort. So then i fixed it by adding a subquery to first extract the data I want with `WERE`  clause then I used `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * from `posts` as `p` 
        WHERE 
           `p`.`long`>-119.2544681443 
           AND `p`.`long`<-117.9658678557 
           AND `p`.`lat`>32.6844318557 A
           ND `p`.`lat`<34.9730321443  

    ) as posttable 
    order by id desc 
    limit x,n
```

By doing that I achieved the following:

```
id  select_type     table        type   possible_keys   key key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>   ALL    NULL            NULL NULL   NULL    3031    Using filesort
2   DERIVED         p            ALL    NULL            NULL NULL   NULL    232377  Using where
```

Now I filter 232k results using "where" and only orderby and limit 3031 results.

Showing rows 0 - 3030 (3,031 total, Query took 0.1431 sec)

Answer (score 2):

Filter from your results records which appeared on earlier pages by using a `WHERE` clause: then you do not need to specify an offset, only a row count.  For example, keep track of the last id or timestamp seen and filter for only those records with id or timestamp greater than that.

Comment: I have seen that solution but it only allows me to have next page or previous .

Comment: @CrisG: How stable is the data?

Comment: @eggyall I do not understand  your question.

Comment: @CrisG: How often is the table written to (relative to the frequency with which it is read)?

Comment: I have updated the question that should answer your question with my examples.

Comment: @CrisG: It still isn't clear how often your data is written vs read, which is key to understanding what cacheing possibilities might exist.

Comment: Data is read each time you browse for posts , and traverse on other pages of a search. As for writes , it will be written to when someone makes a post and one gets deleted . The data sets I have now are dummy date to work with.

Comment: I don't know website isn't live, and data is dummy , so something like Craig'slists I am guessing 100 read to 1 write ratio

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately mysql has to read [and earlier sort] all the 20000 rows before it outputs your 30 results. if you can try narrowing down your search using filtering on indexed columns within WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Few remarks.

given that you `order by id`, it means that on each page you have id for first and last record, so rather than limit 200000, you should use where id > $last_id limit 20 and that would be blazingly fast.

drawback is obviously that you cannot offer "last" page or any page in between, if id's are not sequential (deleted in between). you may then use combination of the last known id and offset + limit combination.

and obviously, having proper indexes will also help sorting and limiting.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you only have a primary key index. you might want to define an index on the fields you use, such as:

```
create index idx_posts_id on posts (`id` ASC);
create index idx_posts_id_timestamp on posts (`id` ASC, `timestamp` ASC);
```

having a regular index on your key field, besides your primary unique key index, usually helps speed up mysql, by, A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql loses quite a bit of performance with a large offset: from the [mysqlPerformance blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/):

Beware of large LIMIT Using index to sort is efficient if you need first few rows, even if some extra filtering takes place so you need to scan more rows by index then requested by LIMIT. However if you’re dealing with LIMIT query with large offset efficiency will suffer. LIMIT 1000,10 is likely to be way slower than LIMIT 0,10. It is true most users will not go further than 10 page in results, however Search Engine Bots may very well do so. I’ve seen bots looking at 200+ page in my projects. Also for many web sites failing to take care of this provides very easy task to launch a DOS attack – request page with some large number from few connections and it is enough. If you do not do anything else make sure you block requests with too large page numbers.

For some cases, for example if results are static it may make sense to precompute results so you can query them for positions.
So instead of query with LIMIT 1000,10 you will have WHERE position between 1000 and 1009 which has same efficiency for any position (as long as it is indexed)

Comment: yes but what if posts are deleted and your missing 1005-1007 .. and u want 10... u will only receive only 7 results not 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AUTO INCREMENT you may use:

`SELECT * 
FROM`posts
`WHERE`id`>= 200000 ORDER BY`id`DESC
LIMIT 200000 , 30`

This way mysql will have to traverse only rows above 200000.

Comment: but even if rows are deleted, auto increment counter never goes down!

Comment: for example:
 `1 ------ record a ---------- detail a
 2--------record b ---------- detail b`
if record 2 is deleted and a new record is inserted data will be:
` 1 ------ record a ---------- detail a
 3--------record c ---------- detail c`